# Django Class Based Views keep url parameters in session

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a django listview working fine.

Its receive url parameters to filter data. 
Its paginated.

Now, I want to maintain these data along the user session. (page number and url parameters).

Example:

- I'm in the products list view.
- I search for 'foo'
- I select page 2
- And then, I click in any product detail.
- The page will redirect to detail view.

When I return to product list view, I whant to keep the search argument 'foo' and selected page 2.

What is the better way to do this?

I'm using Django 2.0.6

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=150)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
```

Views.py

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    model = Product
    paginated_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Product.objects.all()

        name = self.request.GET.get('name', None)
        if name:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=name)

        return queryset
```

Urls.py

```
path('products/', views.ProductList.as_view(), name='product_list'),
```

Comment: You can store your desired data into `django session` or like the other answer keep them in the URL and access them via `GET` requests.

Answer (score 4):

For this you have to put the URL as a get request so that you can fetch the get values form the URL and use them in your filter to maintain your selection like:

```
url/?variable=value
```

Then in your Django view, you can access this by `request.GET.get('variable')` and pass this as the context in your HTML render page then use that variable in your filter selection.

**Setting variable in session:**

For setting the variable in the session you can set it by:

```
request.session['variable'] = 'value'
```

and this value can be retrieve by:

```
if 'variable' in request.session:
    variable1 = request.session['variable']
```

You can refer [this docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).

Answer (score 0):

One common trick I use to do this is to use **GET parameters** and save directly the entire url in session (it saves time compared to saving each individual parameter individually)

```py
class ProductList(ListView):
    model = Product
    paginated_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):

        self.request.session['saved_product_list_url'] = self.request.get_full_path()
        ....
```

Then you can use it like this in templates :

```html
<a href="{% if request.session.saved_product_list_url %}{{ request.session.saved_product_list_url }}{% else %}{% url 'product_list' %}{% endif %}">product list</a>
```

Or like this in views :

```py
saved_product_list_url = self.request.session.get('saved_product_list_url')
if saved_product_list_url:
    return redirect(saved_product_list_url)
else:
    return redirect('product_list')
```

Also in your filter form you should add a "reset filters" like this :

```html
<a href="{% url 'product_list' %}">reset filters</a>
```